# Translate Guestbook

Tags: i18n-l10n, 7

I am trying to create a website in 2 languages, Greek and English. While I translated almost everything, I can't seem to get Guestbook to translate. It only shows in 1 language. Any ideas of how to use the Guestbook module in a  multilingual way? The module I am using is [this](http://drupal.org/project/guestbook).

Comment: use i18n module

Comment: I am using it. So there is a workaround that with i18n that allows this(?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download Guestbook project [translations from here](http://localize.drupal.org/translate/downloads?project=guestbook).